# how do I override a property of UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios9, xcode7

I have a subclass of UIViewController, but I want it to have the property:

```
@proprty (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view
```

instead of the normal:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView * __null_unspecified view
```

which is defined in the UIViewController.h.

can I do that? if yes, then how?
thank you.

Comment: do you want property of UIViewController

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;
it then simply you can achive by this

Comment: @JagveerSingh i meant that i want to override the view property of UIViewController in the subclass, not create a new property

Comment: if yuu made property in .h file then you can modified whenever you want

Comment: @NitzanR: What you want, could you please explain in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override the method  **view:** in your **UIViewController** subclass

```
-(UIView *)view
{

 UIView *customView= [super view];
[customView setSomething:something];
[customView addSubview:someView];
return  customView;
}

@proprty (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view
```

this will create `getter` and `setter` methods in UIViewController namely

```
-(UIView *)view; //getter
-(void)setView:(UIView *)view; //setter
```

have a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) for more info.